# How to rebase to parent of the parent branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, rebase

Branched out from master to featureA branch.
from featureA branch, branched out to featureB branch

How to rebase the featureB to master such that, all commits of featureA are avoided. Basically rebase featureB to master from the commit where featureA was branched out from?

Comment: Are they even going to be compatible? If B doesn't actually need any of the commits from A why not just drop them via interactive rebase?

Comment: Worth noting: *Commits* have parent/child relationships. *Branch names* do not. There's no such thing as a "parent branch", although humans speaking loosely about Git will use that phrase (technically incorrectly).

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for `git rebase --onto`:

```
git rebase --onto master featureA featureB
```

In addition the [the `git-rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase),
[this article](https://womanonrails.com/git-rebase-onto) has a good review of using the `--onto` flag.

---

If I start with `featureB` looking like this:

```
$ git log --oneline
244b8f1 (HEAD -> featureB) commit D
238a93a (featureA) commit C
3666cb0 commit B
c2f04ec (main) commit A
```

Then running:

```
$ git rebase --onto main featureA featureB
```

Results in `featureB` updated to look like this:

```
$ git log --oneline
5608930 (HEAD -> featureB) commit D
c2f04ec (main) commit A
```

Answer (score -1):

`git rebase master featureB` should only rebase featureB -> master while avoiding featureA completely.

To confirm changes before you do this, you can always attach the interactive flag with `-i`. So the full command would look something like:
`git rebase master featureB -i`

Comment: This is going to be a no-op: `featureB` includes all the commits in `featureA`.